# Hadoop copyToLocalFile failing in Yarn cluster mode

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hdfs, hadoop-yarn

I was trying to copy a file to local from HDFS using Hadoop's copyToLocalFile function from my Spark2 application.

```
  val hadoopConf = new Configuration()
  val hdfs = FileSystem.get(hadoopConf)

  val src = new Path("/user/yxs7634/all.txt")
  val dest = new Path("file:///home/yxs7634/all.txt")
  hdfs.copyToLocalFile(src, dest)
```

The above code is working fine when I submit my spark application in Yarn client mode. But, It keeps failing with the below exception in Yarn cluster mode.

```
18/10/03 12:18:40 ERROR yarn.ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/yxs7634/all.txt (Permission denied)
```

Answer (score 1):

In yarn-cluster mode the driver is also handled by yarn and the selected driver node may not be the one where you're submitting the job. Hence for this job to work in yarn-cluster mode I believe you need to place the local file in all the spark nodes in the cluster.

Answer (score 1):

In yarn mode, the spark job is submitted through YARN.
The driver would be started on a different node.

To tackle this issue, you can use a distributed file system like HDFS to store your file and then giving the absolute path.

eg:

```
val src = new Path("hdfs://nameservicehost:8020/user/yxs7634/all.txt")
```

Comment: Are you missing the site xmls  like hdfs-site.xml ? Can you check whether the filesystem instance that you created is the Distributed FS used to access HDFS?

Answer (score 0):

You have a permission denied error, I mean, the user you are using to submit the job is not able to access the file. The directory should have at least read permission to user "other", something like this: `-rw-rw-r--`

Can you paste the permissions of the directory and the file? The command is

```
hdfs dfs -ls /your-directory/
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Spark server running under one user (for ex. "spark"), and file in code stored in other user "yxs7634" directory. 
In cluster mode user "spark" does not allows to write in "yxs7634" user dir, and such exception occurs.

Additional permission for Spark user to write in "/home/yxs7634" is required.

In local mode worked fine, because Spark runs under "yxs7634" user.